# save form data from pure html to datastore

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have a simple form

```
<form name="input" action="" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" id = "xxx">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

On view.py I want to write a function to get value that user input

```
def add(request):
if request.method =="POST":
       abc=request.args.get('xxx')

return render_to_response('myapp/addtour.html')
```

But it does not work. Please tell me how to do it in Google App Engine or Django

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: You're checking for POST while your form uses GET -- the if block will never fire.

2: `xxx` is an HTML ID - it has nothing to do with GET/POST. The name parameter does. So `request.GET.get('user')` - not `'xxx'`